# ASP.NET Core MVC - NETSDK1018 Invalid Nuget version string 'Win10 - 1709 - Build - 1.5.3' - after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC website that I have been developing on a Windows 8 PC on Visual Studio 2017. I've just swapped out my laptop for a Windows 10 one and downloaded and reinstalled Visual Studio 2017, but now I can't build my solution.

When I go to Build > Rebuild Solution (or any other similar action), I get the following error message:

> NETSDK1018 - Invalid Nuget version string 'Win10 - 1709 - Build - 1.5.3'

From my Googling, this appears to match a Windows 10 build version, so I'm guessing the wrong value is getting passed in somewhere?

Double-clicking the error message takes me to a file called *Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets* (which I don't have authority to amend), highlighting the below:

```
<GetAssemblyVersion Condition="'$(AssemblyVersion)' == ''" NuGetVersion="$(Version)">
    <Output TaskParameter="AssemblyVersion" PropertyName="AssemblyVersion" />
</GetAssemblyVersion>
```

I'm not sure whether this is related or a separate issue but, I have no Nuget packages installed and when I try to install *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*, for example, I get:

> The operation failed as details for project *[project name]* could not be loaded.

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated, as I'm currently totally unable to work with my website!

ADDITIONAL: I have now downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2019 and I'm getting the same error message there :(

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was caused by an environment variable named VERSION that was set in our build script for our own internal purposes. Apparently the NuGet parts of msbuild script will read that value if it exists.